# Placeholder color for paper-textarea in Polymer 1.0

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have not found a way to set the placeholder text color for paper-textarea in Polymer 1.0. When using paper-input, the color seems to follow the label color(?!) I have tried the following with no success:

```
paper-textarea {
    --paper-input-container-label: { color: red };
    --paper-input-container-input: { color: green };
    /* could use a "--paper-input-container-placeholder"! */

}
```

and

```
paper-textarea /deep/ ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #f4b400;
}

paper-textarea /deep/ ::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #f4b400;
}

paper-textarea /deep/ :-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #f4b400;
}
```

The latter from Polymer 0.5, i think. Any ideas?

Comment: you have to avoid using `/deep/` since it will be deprecated

Answer (score 4):

Try to add the following:

```
--paper-input-container-color: blue;
```

Comment: @Syntax42, I edited the answer which should now be correct! :)